# Why are Exp[3] and 2 treated differently within Complex?

Tags: complex

Why doesn't the last command below split the complex number into its real and imaginary parts?

```
Complex[2,2]
(* 2 + 2 I *)
Complex[N[Exp[3]], N[Exp[3]]]
(* 20.0855 + 20.0855 I *)
Complex[Exp[3],Exp[3])
(* Complex[E^3,E^3] *)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I understand why this can be very confusing, but essentially

```
Complex[Exp[3],Exp[3]]
```

is *invalid syntax*.  Do not do this.

[`Complex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Complex.html) is an atomic type ([`AtomQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AtomQ.html)).  It is not a compound expression with head `Complex` and two arguments.  It is a fundamental type that is indivisible.

What happens when you evaluate `Complex[1,2]`?  What you type here is indeed a compound expression with head `Complex` and two integer arguments.  However, it evaluates to an atomic integer-based complex immediately.

```
AtomQ[Complex[1, 2]]
(* True *)

AtomQ[Unevaluated@Complex[1, 2]]
(* False *)
```

The fundamental complex type can be either integer-based or real-based, and that's it.  It cannot contain arbitrary symbolic expressions.

If you put such symbolic expressions into `Complex[...]`, it simply won't evaluate.  What you get is a compound expression that is not usable as a complex number.  It is not of the atomic `Complex` type.  `Im`, `Re`, `Abs`, `ComplexExpand`, etc. won't handle it.

```
z = Complex[1, Sqrt[2]];

AtomQ[z]
(* False *)

{Re[z], Im[z], Abs[z]}
(* {Re[Complex[1, Sqrt[2]]], Im[Complex[1, Sqrt[2]]], Abs[Complex[1, Sqrt[2]]]} *)
```

The correct way to represent such number is `Exp[3] + I*Exp[3]` instead.  The structure will then be like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, quite clear. Is there a way to have E^3+E^3 I display as E^3+E^3 I and not as (1+I) E^3?

Comment: +1. The symbol `Complex` behaves similarly to `Rational` for the construction of the respective objects. Arguments of the former must be `NumberQ` and arguments of the latter must be `IntegerQ` for the construction to take place.

Comment: @FernandoSaldanha You can always do something like `With[{re = Re[#], im = Im[#]}, TraditionalForm[HoldForm[re + im I]]] &`